# Subscript out of range when accessing another workbook using a variable for the tab name

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

Can anyone help me resolve a problem that I encounter when trying to access an external workbook/worksheet when using a variable name.

I need to open an external workbook and select a particular sheet name
when I harcode the Tabname it works but when I use a variable I get a Subscript out of range error.

I have included the sub below and I call the routine with

```
 GetDatafromWB FullPandF, strDataImport, "ImportData"

 Sub GetDatafromWB(OtherWB As String, TabName As String, strUser As String)

Dim customBook As Workbook
Dim customFilename As String
Dim customWorkbook As Workbook
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet

' Tabname in this instance is "Aug 2013"

strImpSheet = TabName
strUserSheet = strUser


' set active workbook as the target
Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(strUserSheet)

' get the custom workbook
customFilename = OtherWB
Set customWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(customFilename)


' ****************************** This needs to be changed to a variable ****************************
' ************************************ Currently Hardcoded *****************************************
Set sourceSheet = customWorkbook.Worksheets("Aug 2013")

' Set sourceSheet = customWorkbook.Worksheets(strImpSheet)    generates a subscript out of range error

targetSheet.Range("A3", "I400").Value = sourceSheet.Range("A3", "I400").Value

' Close customer workbook
customWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set sourceSheet = customWorkbook.Worksheets("Aug 2013")` If this is working then and you are getting a `subscript out of range error` when using a valriable then I guess the `TabName` has an extra space(s).. Try this.. `strImpSheet = Trim(TabName)`

Comment: Also Debug and check if `TabName` i.e `strDataImport` has the correct sheet name...

Comment: Many Thanks for your quick response, I included the Trim command and this made no difference also using debug and adding a watch on the variable strImpSheet is set as Aug 2013 as it should be with no additional spaces.  Additionally if I use the index number this as works as well

Comment: In Immediate window type this `?targetWorkbook.Name` do you get the correct workbook's name? The reason why I am asking this is because you have used `ActiveWorkbook` and that might not be the workbook that you actually want to work with...

Comment: ?targetWorkbook.Name
MasterEnquiryLog.xlsm ''' This is where the data needs to copied and is correct
?targetsheet.Name
ImportData  - This is the tabname to be copied into
?customworkbook.Name
SG_Enquiry Log 2013.xlsx  - This is the worksheet to get the data from and it's the "Aug 2013" tab that needs to be read.

Comment: So to confirm `Aug 2013` is in `SG_Enquiry Log 2013.xlsx`?

Comment: Yes,  I have copied the watch error message  Watch :   : customWorkbook.Worksheets(strImpSheet) : <Subscript out of range> : Integer : Module1.GetDatafromWB.  I don't know if this will help.  What it should do is read and copy the info from SG_Enquiry Log 2013.xlsx Worksheet -  Aug 2013.  and copy this into MasterEnquiryLog - ImportData.  The reason the sheet name needs to be a variable is they can choose what month and what year they want to import.

Comment: What happens when you type this in the Immediate window.. `?strImpSheet = "Aug 2013"` If it gives you true then I need to see your `SG_Enquiry Log 2013.xlsx` file

Comment: ?strImpSheet = "Aug 2013"
False
 it returns false

Comment: There you go :) Your sheet names are not matching. Next step... What does `?strImpSheet` and `?len(strImpSheet )` give you...

Comment: You are a genius !!!  Bad programming on my behalf I was not trimming the month and the year before joining them together.  Thanky you very much you have stopped me from going mad..lol

Comment: Glad to be of help :) You can post an answer and accept your answer :)